# How to return matrix columns as lists in Python

Tags: python, matrix, nested-lists

Assuming I have the following matrix:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3], 
          [4,5,6], 
          [7,8,9]]
```

How do I create a function that returns the columns as lists as shown in the list below, without using shortcuts? Thanks in advance.

```
new_matrix = [[1,4,7], 
              [2,5,8], 
              [3,6,9]]
```

Comment: Try `list(zip(*matrix))`. Check my answer for how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "no shortcuts" I assume you mean using `numpy.transpose` or other libraries. Without the use of those, you can actually get a transpose of a list of lists by zipping the rows of the matrix `list(zip(*matrix))`. This will give you a transposed list of tuples. You can then iterate and convert the tuples back to lists.

Try this -

```
new_matrix = [list(i) for i in zip(*matrix)]
new_matrix


##### OR #####
## new_matrix = list(map(list,zip(*matrix)))
```

```
[[1, 4, 7], 
 [2, 5, 8], 
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

---

"Shortcut" way might be `np.array(matrix).T`, but that will require multiple data type conversions.